# LabVIEW corrupt the .xlsx file when crash

Tags: xlsx, labview

I meet a problem in my workplace, with one of the older codes (written in 2015 LabVIEW). The problematic part of the program was writing test data into an xlsx file and usually, once or twice a week LabVIEW crashed and corrupted the xlxs file. That means a serious data loss and I would like to fix it. We use LabVIEW Viewpoint Xlsx Toolkit to edit the excel files. I made a few screenshots where I think the problem happening.
[image]
[image]

Things what i tried:

- Breakpoint the code and kill LabVIEW from the task manager when a file was open.
- Write data continuously into the xlsx file and kill the program at random moments.
- Write that much data that cause memory issue and break the code

None of my tries ended up with a corrupted xlsx file, the document always was openable and contained the older data!

Any tips are welcome because I'm pretty much out of ideas!

Thanks in advance, Peter

Comment: If data loss is costly, note that this may occur even if you fix the bug, e.g. through power loss. A common technique to minimize the risk: Write to a copy of the file, flush file buffers (https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/glang/flush_file.html), then rename the copy to the original. This should guarantee that either the original or the fully written replacement survive

Comment: How often do you write to file? How many rows/columns does file have?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the raw xml files when it has crashed?  Rename the "filename.xlsx" to "filename.zip" and you'll be able to poke around.

Comment: Dear @Homer512 flush file would be a great idea, but that vi opens excel workbook reference and flush file only accept file reference so can't use it.

Comment: Dear @kosist when I tested I wrote 10-20k rows in seconds. A regular measurement file contains 1335 rows and those created from 10:47 till 21:06

Comment: Dear @ben unfortunately, I don't have any corrupted files yet but I asked them to send me one is it possible

Comment: If you don't find a way to pass a file ref to the xlsx writer, you can re-open the file and flush it.

Comment: The real issue here is that your application crashes. Are you sure all references are getting closed? Does your application call the .NET garbage collector explicitly? Did you monitor memory and open references usage?